# How to get scoring of highlighted results in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, scoring, elasticsearch-php

Unable to get solution for the following requirement. Can anyone suggest on this please ?

- I have a ES query that searches for 4 fields in my index and provides highlighted result. But i want to score the highlighted fields of every single document.
- Although i'm able to get Score for every document but i want to fetch score of highlighted fields of each document.

### Actuall scenario why i need this

i have 4 field in my index that are title, description, subtitle, chapter and I'm performing search operation in all these fields so title is fixed which i will show anyhow in frontend. Then from other 3 fields i will check which is more relevant to the search keyword and i will show that because i will show only one field from th 3 fields along with title in frontend.

### Solutions Tried

- Tried using **explain=true** but its very complex and i didn't get any key to fetch score of each fields.
- Tried **sub_searches** but didn't worked for me.

### Here is my current query

```
$filesQuery['body'] = [
            'size' => 5,
            'query' => [
                'function_score' => [
                    'query' => [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => [
                                [
                                    'bool' => [
                                        'should' => [
                                            [
                                                'match' => [
                                                    'title' => [
                                                        'query' => $request['query'],
                                                        'boost' => 4
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'wildcard' => [
                                                    'title' => [
                                                        'value' => '*' . $request['query'] . '*',
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'match' => [
                                                    'description' => [
                                                        'query' => $request['query'],
                                                        'boost' => 3
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'wildcard' => [
                                                    'description' => [
                                                        'value' => '*' . $request['query'] . '*',
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'match' => [
                                                    'chapters_v1.chapter' => [
                                                        'query' => $request['query'],
                                                        'boost' => 3
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'wildcard' => [
                                                    'chapters_v1.chapter' => [
                                                        'value' => '*' . $request['query'] . '*',
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'match' => [
                                                    'subtitle' => [
                                                        'query' => $request['query'],
                                                        'boost' => 1
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                'wildcard' => [
                                                    'subtitle' => [
                                                        'value' => '*' . $request['query'] . '*',
                                                    ],
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'term' => [
                                        'team_id' => $teamId,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'collapse' => [
                'field' => 'file_id',
            ],
            'aggs' => [
                'total_files' => [
                    'cardinality' => [
                        'field' => 'file_id',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'highlight' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'plain',
                        "fragment_size" => 70,
                        "no_match_size" => 70,
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'type' => 'plain',
                        "fragment_size" => 55,
                        "no_match_size" => 55,
                    ],
                    'subtitle' => [
                        'type' => 'plain',
                        'number_of_fragments' => 1,
                        'fragment_size' => 30,
                    ],
                    'chapters_v1.chapter' => [
                        'type' => 'plain',
                        'number_of_fragments' => 1,
                        'fragment_size' => 30,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'track_total_hits' => true,
        ];
```

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of the query you are using? I have some ideas on how to help, but I cannot know for sure how to address this without knowing what your current query looks like.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminTrent i have updated the query on question itself. Please have a look if you can suggest anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to do this is to combine your individual queries for individual fields into their own `bool` queries. Then you can name the `bool` query and rely on query names & scoring to get the matching queries & their contributing scores.

It seems that the `function_score` action does nothing, so I removed that in my example, but of course, if its critical, you can add it back.

Still all `should` clauses, but now each field is contained in its own `bool` with a `_name` matching that field.

`include_named_queries_score` is a search parameter added in 8.8. This will not only return the query names that matched, but their contributing score.

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "_name": "title",
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "title": {
                            "query": "<your_query_here>",
                            "boost": 4
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "title": {
                            "value": "*<your_query_here>*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "_name": "description",
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "description": {
                            "query": "<your_query_here>",
                            "boost": 3
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "description": {
                            "value": "*<your_query_here>*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "_name": "chapters",
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "chapters_v1.chapter": {
                            "query": "<your_query_here>",
                            "boost": 3
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "chapters_v1.chapter": {
                            "value": "*<your_query_here>*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "_name": "subtitle",
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "subtitle": {
                            "query": "<your_query_here>",
                            "boost": 1
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "subtitle": {
                            "value": "*<your_query_here>*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "team_id": "<team_id_here>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "file_id"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "total_files": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "file_id"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 70,
        "no_match_size": 70
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 55,
        "no_match_size": 55
      },
      "subtitle": {
        "type": "plain",
        "number_of_fragments": 1,
        "fragment_size": 30
      },
      "chapters_v1.chapter": {
        "type": "plain",
        "number_of_fragments": 1,
        "fragment_size": 30
      }
    }
  },
  "include_named_queries_score": true,
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

Comment: its giving following error
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a VALUE_BOOLEAN in [include_named_queries_score].","line":1,"col":1286}],

on this line : "include_named_queries_score": true,

IF i remove this line then query works, but again then i not getting any scores

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using @kishanmaharana? Its only available in 8.8+. If you are on 8.8+, could you test it in Kibana Console? I am ignorant of how our PHP client works (or PHP in general).